# Ionic 7 / Angular Invalid Form Control Validation

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic 7 app and I have a form that validates a phone number to show the send button, but for some reason that I do not understand it is being invalidated since the regular expression is fine in my opinion but I think that may be where the problem lies. let me share a part of code:

**Html Component:**

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <h3 class="tittle">Type Cellphone</h3>
  <form [formGroup]="phoneForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input class="margin-top"
        label="Número de celular"
        type="tel"
        formControlName="phoneNum"
        labelPlacement="floating"
        placeholder="+57 (xxx) xxx-xxxx"
        [maskito]="phoneMask"
        [maskitoElement]="maskPredicate">
      </ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  <div class="ion-text-center margin-top">
    <ion-button type="submit" *ngIf="phoneForm.valid" fill="outline">Send SMS</ion-button>
  </div>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

**TS Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaskitoOptions, MaskitoElementPredicateAsync } from '@maskito/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-phone-method',
  templateUrl: './phone-method.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./phone-method.component.scss'],
})
export class PhoneMethodComponent  implements OnInit {
//---
  phoneForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.phoneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      phoneNum: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.pattern("/^\\+\\d{2}\\s\\(\\d{3}\\)\\s\\d{3}-\\d{4}$/")])],
    });
  }

  submitForm() {
    let phone=this.phoneForm.get('phoneNum')?.value;
    if (this.phoneForm.valid) {
      console.log(phone);
    }
  }

  readonly phoneMask: MaskitoOptions = {
    mask: ['+','5','7',' ','(',/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,')',' ',/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,'-',/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,/\d/],
  };
  readonly maskPredicate: MaskitoElementPredicateAsync = async (el) => (el as HTMLIonInputElement).getInputElement();

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Can someone help me figure out what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the error was where I suspected, this is the corrected code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaskitoOptions, MaskitoElementPredicateAsync } from '@maskito/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-phone-method',
  templateUrl: './phone-method.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./phone-method.component.scss'],
})
export class PhoneMethodComponent  implements OnInit {
  phoneForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    /**this.phoneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      phoneNum: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,])],
    });*/

    this.phoneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      phoneNum: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\+\d{2}\s\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$/)])
    ]});
  }

  submitForm() {
    let phone=this.phoneForm.get('phoneNum')?.value;
    if (this.phoneForm.valid) {
      console.log(phone);
    }
  }

  readonly phoneMask: MaskitoOptions = {
    mask: ['+','5','7',' ','(',/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,')',' ',/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,'-',/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,/\d/],
  };

  readonly maskPredicate: MaskitoElementPredicateAsync = async (el) => (el as HTMLIonInputElement).getInputElement();

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```